# How to construct properly a html string in C#

Tags: c#, html

I need to create this html string :

```
<table cellspacing="2" style="width:100%">
    <tr height="30" nowrap="NOWRAP" width="200" bgcolor="#f4f4f4">
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Category</th> 
      <th>Price</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Replace</td>
      <td>Replace</td>
      <td>Replace</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I have a List of items that I intend to replace. I Was trying to do with `StringBuilder` but it wasn't working!

Comment: What does "it was not working" mean? Did your application crash? Did you get an unexpected result? What *exactly* happened? Also you need to supply the code you have so far, you can replace / build a string in *many* different ways and until you clarify *how* you are doing this no one can answer your question.

Comment: When I tried to create something like `cellspacing="2"` it wasn't working. And the "td's" has to be replaced by the items from a List.

Comment: Maybe its worth a look into the [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@` for verbatim string and double the `"` marks to escape them. Also you can use `string.Format` with `{}` placeholders to inject values although they are not html encoded so if you have characters like `<` in the string they would need to be escaped. This is 1 variant of many and without you sharing what you have so far it is as good as any answer you might get.

```
var html = string.Format(
@"<table cellspacing=""2"" style=""width:100%"">
    <tr height=""30"" nowrap=""NOWRAP"" width=""200"" bgcolor=""#f4f4f4"">
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Category</th> 
      <th>Price</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>{0}</td>
      <td>{1}</td>
      <td>{2}</td>
  </tr>
</table>", listItem[0], listItem[1], listItem[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I need!